# How to Error Handle within a For-Loop that retrieves Yahoo Finance data from a list of ticker symbols

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling

So I have written some code to pull csv files off yahoo finance using a "list" of Ticker symbols contained within a 1-dimensional array.  The challenge I'm having is that one of the ticker symbols might not have any data (or may have been entered wrong).  So I built a tryCatch command, but it's not working very well.  Below is my code (which I access using source("Name of the code"), followed by the error it generates:

```
#URL Builder for Yahoo Finance
 #Requests Input from User, Builds URL, downloads csv.file from site
 #Requests are for:
      #Ticker (2-4 letter - character string)
      #Start Month (00 - 11 integer)
      #Start Day (1 - 31 integer)
      #Start Year (Four digit integer)
      #End Month (00 - 11 integer)
      #End Day (1 - 31 integer)
      #End Year (Four digit integer)

      #Retrieve Ticker File
       setwd(personal_directory)
      #tickers            <- read.csv("Tickers.csv")

      #Here are some example tickers, since you will not have the Ticker.csv file (the S ticker generates the error to be handled
       tickers            <- data.frame(Ticker = c("XOM", "DVN", "S")) 
       tickers            <- tickers[order(tickers[,1]),]
       setwd("Ticker Data")

      #Functions
       Get_Month_Begin    <- function(){as.numeric(readline("Enter the start month 00 - 11(MM):>>> "))}
       Get_Day_Begin      <- function(){as.numeric(readline("Enter the start day (1-31) :>>> "))}
       Get_Year_Begin     <- function(){as.numeric(readline("Enter the start year (YYYY) :>>> "))}
       Get_Month_End      <- function(){as.numeric(readline("Enter the end month (MM) :>>> "))}
       Get_Day_End        <- function(){as.numeric(readline("Enter the end day (1-31) :>>> "))}
       Get_Year_End       <- function(){as.numeric(readline("Enter the end year :>>> "))}

      #Function Calls
       Month_Begin        <- Get_Month_Begin()
       Day_Begin          <- Get_Day_Begin()
       Year_Begin         <- Get_Year_Begin()
       Month_End          <- Get_Month_End()
       Day_End            <- Get_Day_End()
       Year_End           <- Get_Year_End()

      #Build URL
      #Example URL: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csvs=DVN&a=00&b=1&c=1992&d=11&e=31&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv
       CSV_Base_URL       <- "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="
       yahoo_data_date_format <- "%Y-%m-%d"

       for(i in 1:nrow(tickers)){
           Ticker             <- tickers[i, 1]
           CSV_URL_Complete   <- paste(CSV_Base_URL,Ticker,"&a=",Month_Begin,"&b=",Day_Begin,"&c=",Year_Begin,"&d=",Month_End,"&e=",Day_End,"&f=",Year_End,"&g=d&ignore=.csv",sep="")

            #Download CSV
             options(warn=2)
             potential_error   <- tryCatch(Yahoo_Finance_TBL <- read.csv(CSV_URL_Complete), error = function(e) e)

            if(!inherits(potential_error, "error")){
                Yahoo_Finance_TBL              <- Yahoo_Finance_TBL[,c(1,7)]
                colnames(Yahoo_Finance_TBL)    <- gsub(" ", ".", colnames(Yahoo_Finance_TBL))
                Yahoo_Finance_TBL[, 1]         <- as.Date(Yahoo_Finance_TBL[, 1], yahoo_data_date_format)

                #Write CSV File
                 write.csv(Yahoo_Finance_TBL, file=paste(Ticker,"_Yahoo_Finance_File.csv", sep=""), row.names=FALSE)
             }
       }
```

This code generates the following error:

```
Error in if (file == "") file <- stdin() else { : 
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I know this is a problem in the if-condition, and I'm wondering if I need to put an "==TRUE" statement in there somewhere.

Thank you for your help!

NOTE:
I have run the code without the for-loop, simply setting Ticker <- "S" to see what type of error is generated.  This turns out to be a warning (as opposed to an error), so I wrote the following code (edited above):

```
options(warn = 2)
```

This makes all warnings errors, but there is still no joy.

Comment: Instead of giving functions that require the user to type in values, just hardcode the values for us so that we can all reproduce the same thing.  e.g. instead of `Month_Begin <- Get_Month_Begin()`, just show us `Month_Begin <- 1` for the example's sake.  Also, things like `setwd(personal_directory)` and `setwd("Ticker Data")` are not reproducible by us.

Comment: Just in case you have not heard about the `quantmod` package: It has a function `getSymbols` that handles data download from yahoo and other sources. BTW: Another interesting website that provides data and an `R` interface is http://www.quandl.com/ (just found it recently and have had the time to tested it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you show is probably coming from `write.table` which is called by `write.csv`. The error is telling you that `file` is missing (`NA`).  However, I get other errors, one of which is `Error in 1:nrow(tickers) : argument of length 0` which I'll explain more below.

I'd store the tickers as a character vector instead of storing the them in a `data.frame`, but if you're going to store them in a `data.frame` you have to be careful about 2 things: `stringsAsFactors` and `drop`.

`tickers <- data.frame(Ticker = c("XOM", "DVN", "S"))` stores your tickers as factors

```
> str(tickers)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Ticker: Factor w/ 3 levels "DVN","S","XOM": 3 1 2
```

`tickers <- tickers[order(tickers[,1]),]` replaces the `data.frame` with with a `Factor` vector, because by default `drop=TRUE` in `[.data.frame`.

```
> tickers[order(tickers[,1]),]
[1] DVN S   XOM
Levels: DVN S XOM
```

However, later you treat it as if it is still a 1-column `data.frame`: `nrow(tickers)` is NULL, and `tickers[1, 1]` is an error.

You could either change the code that subsets the vector, or use `drop=FALSE` to keep it as a `data.frame`

```
> tickers[order(tickers[,1]),,drop=FALSE]
  Ticker
2    DVN
3      S
1    XOM
```

If you're going to use a `data.frame` for this, I suggest using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` so that your tickers will be stored as `character`

```
> tickers <- data.frame(Ticker = c("XOM", "DVN", "S"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> str(tickers)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Ticker: chr  "XOM" "DVN" "S"
```

---

Finally, instead of `1:nrow(tickers)` you should use `seq_len(tickers)`.  Otherwise, you will get unexpected results if `nrow(tickers) is 0

```
>for(i in 1:0) print(i)
[1] 1
[1] 0
```

Comment: Thank you for all of the helpful advice.  Just one question on your suggestion regarding my error handler; I am using tryCatch as opposed to try.  Should I then still use "try-error" or should I stick with "error" when using tryCatch?